# ClassFormatError in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a GUI application , written with Java 8.0 and JavaFX8. With the same code, the program runs normally on my windows machine, but on the debian machine, it throws this exeption... 

Does anyone has this problem before?

Thank you.

> Exception in Application start method Exception in thread "Thread-2"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$4/5332343.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Name index 42936 in LocalVariableTable has
>   bad constant type in class file javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at

Comment: Try to clean and build your project before running it.

Comment: i did, it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

After the java FX is re-installed on the debian machine,  the program works normally.